# Google Cloud Message (GCM) sent android is Error inValid Register

Tags: php, android, curl

I'm building a application with Google cloud message (GCM) follow article [androidexample create app to push notify](http://androidexample.com/Android_Push_Notifications_using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=119&aaid=139)

But i have bug when i try sent a notify to Google Server by CURL with link https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send and some field in code

```
 function send_push_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {

    echo implode($registatoin_ids);
    echo implode($message);
    // Set POST variables
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
        'data' => $message,
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    //print_r($headers);
    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    //echo $ch;
    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        echo ("RESULT ERROR :" + $ch);
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));

    }

    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
}
```

I receive a result ERROR when try sent
 [image: Error responve]

So, Could you please help me fix or config to sent message to server, I try make a application to sent notify from server to Android device,
Thank a lot of.

PS:so sorry for my english, Thanks again

Huan

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you used is too old.

Look here:

```
 GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, true);
```

This class is deprecated

As of now you should use **[Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)**